# What can be run through an eval to reload a file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a service that I want to keep up as often as possible and restarting it takes away a few seconds, not to mention interrupts any ongoing processes. If I make a small change to a file and want it to be reloaded, what code can I have eval() to do it?

For example, if I have rng.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}
```

and in another file, index.js

```
const rng = require('./rng.js');
console.log(rng());
```

If I change the 4 in rng.js to a 3, obviously the live code is still using 4 so it won't change, so how can I reload the file, assuming I have access to eval() while the script is running?

Answer (score 0):

For the given example, in node you can pass run time argument.

> node index.js 5 (here 5 is the run time argument)

index.js

```
const rng = require('./rng.js');
var command = process.argv[2];
console.log(command);
console.log(rng(process.argv[2]));
```

rng.js

```
module.exports = function(input) {
       console.log('input',input);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * input);
}
```

or you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon to load changes in live.